# Error while submitting change trust transaction

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, trustline

I created an anchor account which issues `USD` asset. It worked properly.
But now when I modify the program where the anchor issues one more asset called `INR` and I am creating a trustline for both the assets in one transaction builder, it fails.

**Error**

```
data:
      { type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed',
        title: 'Transaction Failed',
        status: 400,
        detail: 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html',
        extras: [Object] } } }
failure Error: Request failed with status code 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\SID\exelis\stellar-sid\new\copy\demo\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\SID\exelis\stellar-sid\new\copy\demo\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\SID\exelis\stellar-sid\new\copy\demo\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

**Code**

```
const stellarServer = new Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

const account = await stellarServer.loadAccount(accountKeypair.publicKey())
const transaction = new TransactionBuilder(account)
  .addOperation(
    Operation.changeTrust({
      asset: AnchorXUSD
    }))
  .addOperation(
    Operation.changeTrust({
      asset: AnchorXINR
    }))  
  .build();

transaction.sign(accountKeypair)

const result = await stellarServer.submitTransaction(transaction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking inside `extras.result_codes` as the error message suggests? The exact reason of why your transaction failed is documented there. In your case it is probably because you did not provide the public key of the account issuer of the assets.

Answer (score 0):

For each change trust transaction you need to specify the asset code and the issuer id. I think issuer id not included in your transaction.